# \cline and first vertical line dosen't work in multi column tables

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to have this behaviour for a certain table in my document:
[image]

Here is the code I'm using and see the second picture for the table I'm getting !

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
natbib=true,
style=numeric,
sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{rotating}
% acronyms and abbreviations will need to put them in a separate file
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{microtype}
% for making the table looks goods
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{skyblue}{RGB}{150,194,255}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{2,40,94}
\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1,\enspace}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,
top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
% for mutil level tables 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\allsectionsfont{\color{darkblue}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\rmfamily\bfseries}p{2cm}}%
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedright\arraybackslash\rmfamily}X}%
\newcolumntype{J}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\rmfamily}X}%
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedleft\arraybackslash\rmfamily}X}%
\rowcolors{2}{blue!05}{skyblue!05}
\bibliography{bib/litterature.bib}{}
\addbibresource{bib/litterature.bib}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begingroup % make the next setting local
    \captionsetup{type=table} % here we want to caption a table
    \caption{Résultat des Algorithmes }
    \label{tab:AlgoResults}
    \noindent
    {\resizebox*{\textwidth}{\textheight}{%
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                \multirow{6}{*}{} Faculté & Dimensions &Modèle&Paramètres &RMSE Train &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{CV Score}&RMSE Test  \\
                \cline{6-7}
                &&&&&M&std& \\
                \cline{1-8}
                &&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&Lasso&D&E&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &Medecine&Elastic Net&F&G&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&LinearSVR&I&J&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&RbfSVR&K&L&M&std& \\
                \cline{1-8}
                \multirow{5}{*}{}
                &&Ridge&${\alpha}$=1 ,solver=cholesky&0.05 : 9\% &0.067: 11.53\%& 0.00454&0.071 : 12.31\% \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&Lasso&${\alpha}$=1e-05,iIter=10000&0.0485 : 8.36\%&0.07 : 12.06\%&0.0036&  0.074: 12.79\%\\
                \cline{3-8}
                Droit&897x 297&Elastic Net&${\alpha}$=1e-05,Iter=10000,l1Ratio=0.5&0.048:8.34\%&0.070
                12.11\%
                &0.0035& 0.0742 : 12.79\%\\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&LinearSVR&kernel=linear&0.052:8.95\%&0.075 :13.045\%&0.00637&0.0740 :12.75\%\\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&RbfSVR&Kernel =Gaussian&0.067:11.52\%&0.068 : 11.8\% &0.006& 0.0721 : 12.43\%\\
                \cline{1-8}
                \hline
                \multirow{5}{*}{}
                &&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&Lasso&D&E&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &Économie&Elastic Net&F&G&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&LinearSVR&I&J&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&RbfSVR&K&L&M&std& \\
                \cline{1-8}
                \multirow{5}{*}{}
                &&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&Lasso&D&E&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &Santé&Elastic Net&F&G&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&LinearSVR&I&J&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&RbfSVR&K&L&M&std& \\
                \cline{1-8}
                \multirow{5}{*}{}
                &&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&Lasso&D&E&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &Psychologie&Elastic Net&F&G&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&LinearSVR&I&J&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&RbfSVR&K&L&M&std& \\
                \cline{1-8}
                \multirow{5}{*}{}
                &&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&Lasso&D&E&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &Droit&Elastic Net&F&G&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&LinearSVR&I&J&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&RbfSVR&K&L&M&std& \\
                \cline{1-8}
                \multirow{5}{*}{}
                &&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&Lasso&D&E&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &Santé&Elastic Net&F&G&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&LinearSVR&I&J&M&std& \\
                \cline{3-8}
                &&RbfSVR&K&L&M&std& \\
                \cline{1-8}
    \end{tabular}}}
    \endgroup
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

here is the table I'm getting !
[image]

any help will be appreciate !
Note : I have many other tables in my document and they are displayed as I want but not this one.

Comment: Remove the \rowcolors command.

Comment: Thanks a lot   It works perfect !! I don't know why!! Please tell me what can i do if i want the row color for my tables

Comment: Colors and lines together are difficult. The colors do have the tendency to hide the lines at least in parts, unless you redraw them. This is possible but can take quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dvipsnames,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
natbib=true,
style=numeric,
sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{rotating}
% acronyms and abbreviations will need to put them in a separate file
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,hhline}
\usepackage{microtype}
% for making the table looks goods
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{skyblue}{RGB}{150,194,255}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{2,40,94}
\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1,\enspace}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,
top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
% for mutil level tables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\allsectionsfont{\color{darkblue}}


\bibliography{bib/litterature.bib}{}
\addbibresource{bib/litterature.bib}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\begin{document}
\definecolor{lineCol}{RGB}{220, 140, 90}
\definecolor{tableHeader}{RGB}{120, 35, 35}
\definecolor{tableHeaderB}{RGB}{160, 60, 60}
\definecolor{tableLineOne}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{tableLineTwo}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\definecolor{fiverowscolA}{RGB}{250, 250, 250}
\definecolor{fiverowscolB}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\rowcolors{2}{tableHeader}{tableHeader}
\newcommand{\tableHeaderStyle}{
\rowfont{\leavevmode\color{white}\bfseries}
%\rowcolor{tableHeader}
}
\taburowcolors[2] 2{tableLineOne .. tableLineTwo}
\tabulinesep = ^4mm_3mm
%\everyrow{\tabucline[.4mm white]{}}
\taburulecolor{lineCol}
\begin{table}
   \captionsetup{type=table} % here we want to caption a table
    \caption{Résultat des Algorithmes }
    \label{tab:AlgoResults}
    \noindent
{\resizebox*{\textwidth}{\textheight}{%
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.2pt}
    \extracolsep{0pt}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\tableHeaderStyle
Faculté & Dimensions &Modèle&Paramètres &RMSE Train &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{CV Score}&RMSE Test  \\\hhline{|*{5}{>{\arrayrulecolor{tableHeader}}->{\arrayrulecolor{lineCol}}|}*{2}{-}|*{1}{>{\arrayrulecolor{tableHeader}}->{\arrayrulecolor{lineCol}}|}}%
\tableHeaderStyle\rowcolor{tableHeaderB} 
&&&&&M&std& \\ \hline
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB} &\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&B& C &  D \\ 
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&&E & F  \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&LinearSVR&I&J&M&std&  \\
\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}3}&\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}Medicine}&&&&& I & J  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&Ridge&kernel=linear&0.052:8.95\%&0.075 :13.045\%&0.00637&0.0740 :12.75\% \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA} &\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&B& C &  D \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&Elastic Net&${\alpha}$=1e-05,Iter=10000,l1Ratio=0.5&0.048:8.34\%&0.070 12.11\%  &0.0035& 0.0742 : 12.79\%  \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&& G & H  \\
\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}TestA}&\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}Medicine}&&&&& I & J  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB} &\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&B& C &  D \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&&E & F  \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&& G & H  \\
\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}TestB}&\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}Medicine}&&&&& I & J  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA} &\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&B& C &  D \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&&E & F  \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&& G & H  \\
\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}3}&\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}Medicine}&&&&& I & J  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB} &\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&B& C &  D \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&&E & F  \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&& G & H  \\
\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}3}&\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}Psychologie}&&&&& I & J  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA} &\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&B& C &  D \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&&E & F  \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}&&&&& G & H  \\
\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}3}&\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolA}Medicine}&&&&& I & J  \\ \hline
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&Ridge&A&B&M&std& \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB} &\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&B& C &  D \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&&E & F  \\
\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}&&&&& G & H  \\
\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}3}&\multirow{-5}*{\cellcolor{fiverowscolB}Medicine}&&&&& I & J  \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!! But need the zebra color in the row!! I want to alternate bleu and white columns between line!!!